# Web based Check List Completion App

Tags: web-apps

I am looking for an application where can complete a digital checklist and post back the results.

**Background**: We currently use a paper-based checklist that individuals will complete as they check various items with their vehicle before that take it out on the road (oil, coolant, tires etc). In addition to that, they would also have to complete a separate form for inside the vehicle such as the tools they have on board etc.

**Goal** I am looking for a Web Service either hosted or self-hosted whereby individuals can log in and complete the checklist in real time which can be viewed remotely.

**Requirements** We have looked at safetyculture.io and others, however, these don't seem to be a good fit as they bill per user per month. A web-based is a requirement rather than SmartPhone app. API access to availability would be advantageous. Ideally free / Open Source, but willing to spend money on the right solution. Am also considering Ninja Forms and developing it internally from there. All suggestions welcome.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You might not be looking at a "Checklist" kind of software but rather for a ticketing software.

With a ticketing software, you will also be able to create KPIs.

So for each vehicle coming to your premises for service, you log a ticket with the car/driver details and somebody creates the tasks that are needed to be done.

So every time something is completed, the user will need to log into the system find the ticket related to that car and check the relevant checkbox. This way you will also have a track of the history of what has been done.

I propose Spiceworks and it's free to use with the tasks plugin https://community.spiceworks.com/appcenter/app/plugin_737 but there might be some open source ticketing solutions out there with a tasklist plugin intergrated into their product.

Answer (score 0):

For simplicity and cost sake, I would recommend using [Google Forms](https://www.google.com/forms/about/). You can create a reusable checklist including multiple choice options (if you like). And, when they submit their form it will compile all of the results into a Google spreadsheet that you can download or keep in the browser.

You can brand the form with your logo as well.

The only slight drawback is that you won’t see them checking off each item (literally realtime), but you will see the results as soon as they submit the form (and can be notified by email).